# Website loading issue with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a website http://www.rockdesign.com/
Just today that the website has loading issue. It takes like 1 minutes for the website to load properly, however, if I click on stop loading, the website load perfectly.

Does anyone know what issue it might be ?
Thank you so much !!!

Comment: It load perfect in chrome. Clear you cache.
I feel because of you sliders 10 above make it in ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tracker.js` is failing to load which stalls the page until that times out.  You can use the network tab in the Chrome debugger to see what resources in the page are having difficultly loading.

Comment: @albert - since you are fairly new to StackOverflow, are you aware that you can mark an answer that helped you as the "best answer" by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and that earns some reputation points for both you and the person providing the answer.  After you earn some more privileges from those reputation points, you can also upvote any answer that helped by clicking the up arrow to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.doramo.com/tracker/2/tracker.js"></script>
```

Your page loads fine, save for that script. Your website is waiting for that script to load, and it 'appears' to finish loading when it fails to reach it. I can't even currently ping the doramo servers, so I would suggest making sure the url is correct and then trying again later.